# Sharing resource for multiple instance

Tags: spring-boot, architecture

Consider that we have multiple instance of a micro service. and consider that we have a table whose data should be separated between these multiple instances and processed as scheduled task. What should be the correct way to handle these kind of issues?

For example we have 90 account in one table and 3 different instance of micro service. Each account should be synchronized periodically. I would like this synchronization separated by 3 different instances. In other words, 30 account for each instance.